# IDLE: Your Python may not be configured for Tk

Tags: python, linux, idle-ide

Estou tentando usar o Python no Slackware, no Ubuntu sei como é, mas no Slackware não consegui.

Quando digito no terminal `idle` para abrir o Python, a seguinte mensagem é exibida:

> Your Python may not be configured for Tk

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: O que acontece? qual o erro?

Comment: diz que meu python não esta configurado para tk

Comment: Qual a versão do Python? e qual mensagem é exibida ao tentar usar o `tk`?

Comment: a versão do python é 2.7.5 . Quando coloco no terminar idle para abrir o python sai a msg q o python nao ta configurado para tk..nao tentei usar o tk

Comment: Se você puder [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/146990/edit) a pergunta e colocar as mensagens de erro que aparece, isso pode ajudar na resolução do problema. Veja se você tem esse pacote instalado: http://packages.slackware.com/?r=slackware-current&p=python-setuptools-22.0.5-i586-1.txz

Comment: Pessoal consegui abrir o idle do python no slackware. Digitei no terminal 'sudo slapt-get --install tk', sem as aspas, e instalou o tk. Agoro consigo usar o idle do python

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o AP, o problema foi resolvido ao instalar o `tk`:

```
sudo slapt-get --install tk
```